# Erro ao subir projeto no Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku, graphql

Estou tentando subir meu projeto no heroku e ele me da o seguinte erro:

erro:
`remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ remote:        [INFO] Total time:  9.367 s remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-22T15:44:38Z remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project api-graphql-trainee: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1] remote:        [ERROR] remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. remote:        [ERROR] remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException remote: remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code, remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/ remote: remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app. remote: remote:  !     Push failed remote: Verifying deploy... remote: remote: !       Push rejected to api-larissa. remote: To https://git.heroku.com/api-larissa.git ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/api-larissa.git'`

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.5</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.arphoenix</groupId>
   <artifactId>api-graphql-trainee</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>api-graphql-trainee</name>
   <description>Projeto Crud Spring Boot, Java e GraphQL</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
         <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.3</version>
      </dependency>
<!--      <dependency>-->
<!--         <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>-->
<!--         <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>-->
<!--         <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--      </dependency>-->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
<!--      <dependency>-->
<!--         <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>-->
<!--         <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>-->
<!--         <version>14.0.0</version>-->
<!--      </dependency>-->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.tailrocks.graphql</groupId>
         <artifactId>graphql-datetime-kickstart-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
         <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.27</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
         <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
         <version>1.8.17</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.leangen.graphql</groupId>
         <artifactId>graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.6</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>
                     <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                     <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                  </exclude>
               </excludes>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Comment: **error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/api-larissa.git'** alguma coisa está impedindo o montador de enviar o conteúdo do repositório local para um repositório remoto. Mas ai não diz o que efetivamente seja.

Comment: Veja se a ajuda: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: ele fala isso  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project api-graphql-trainee: Input length = 1 -> mas a minha versão do maven é a 4.0.0

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o erro adicionando essa dependencia

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <!-- Add the following exclusions here. -->
                <configuration>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>properties</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```